# Чем отличаются stateProps от ownProps в react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Чем отличаются stateProps от ownProps в react-redux?
вот статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/314582/
тут говорится что  stateProps  содержит текущее состояние. А что тогда содержится в ownProps?
Когда использовать ownProps, а когда stateProps?
 если я в maspStateToprops получаю через state значение:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({

  value: state.value
 });
```

то в mapDispatchToprops к нему нужно обращаться  как к stateProps или own?

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
   return{
onSubmitForm: (form, values, ownProps.value) => 
 dispatch(submitForm(form, values, ownProps.value)),
```

}};

Comment: Не советовал бы читать советских газет за завтраком... https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Answer (score 3):

`state` - это объект, который хранит состояние приложения, которое вы модифицируете с помощью `redux`.
`ownProps` - это props которые пришли от родительского компонента.